# Multi-personal creation in Genesis or exclusive?

Tags: genesis, john, intertextuality, trinity

At some level, each part of the Trinity could be said to be involved in the "creation"—the Father presumably is aware of the creation and had furnished the designs or forms. However, I would like to explore more on the demiurgical context of creation.

On the one hand, we have a persuasive hermeneutic that the Holy Spirit portion of the Trinity was this force in Genesis 1:2, as this excellent question and answer lays out, accounting for much nuance along the way: [Does Genesis 1:2 refer to the Spirit or a wind?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/does-genesis-12-refer-to-the-spirit-or-a-wind/40214#40214).

While on the other hand, in the prologue of John, the notion that the Logos/Son aspect of the Trinity filled this role is also well-known and has a deep scholarship.

[Cosmology and the Prologue of the Fourth Gospel](https://brill.com/previewpdf/journals/vc/12/1/article-p147_16.xml)

For ease of reference, John 1:3-4:

> <sup>**3**</sup> God created everything through [the Logos], and nothing was created except through him. <sup>**4**</sup> The Logos gave life to everything that was created.

Perhaps it is unrealistic to expect perfect alignment between OT and NT—after all Genesis itself has two cosmogonies.

And as God is Triune, the distinction between the Son and the Holy Spirit may merely be contrived.

However, the constituents of the Godhead do differ, and on occasion much emphasis is placed on these differences (with John 16:7 being an interesting example of this).

**Question**

With all this in mind, what might we be able to methodologically gloss from the accounts of different aspects of the Godhead carrying out the demiurgical function of God's creation: must we accept both Persons are viable or can we narrow the field by even a little bit?

Comment: This question has no answer.  The traditional view is that all three members of the Trinity were involved; just what their function was is not revealed.  therefore, we cannot know because we are not told.

Comment: @Arash Howaida You say "both" but this means 2, before you meantion "Trinity" which implies 3. So I find lack of clarity here. Also "viable" means "capable of working successfully". Matt 28:18 all authority belongs to Jesus so success is inevitable. I think your question is difficult to understand because it is wide ranging.

Comment: If I may push back ever so slightly, Dottard's comment would be a perfectly acceptable as an answer. I would argue the question/hermeneutic is valid, but not all questions/hermeneutics can be clinically resolved. This is my opinion, anwyay.

Comment: @Dottard King David was never 'told' - but he knew that 'the LORD said unto my Lord . . . . . etc.' He was conscious of two persons within Deity. And a third 'take not thy Holy Spirit from me'. The question stops short of this . . . 'part' 'portion' 'aspect' and 'constituent'. (Never 'Person'.)

Comment: Genesis does not contain 'two cosmogenies'. The narrative sets forth two _aspects_ of one cosmogeny.

Comment: @ArashHowaida On second thought, it could be argued we are "told." At least in the prologue of John. For the Spirit's role in Genesis a deeper hermeneutic is needed, but it is provided in the link. I stand behind my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patristic hermeneutics never cease to amaze me. [Tertullian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertullian) was grappling with this question long before I. Below are a few notable takes from him:

Prax. 16

> But you must not suppose that only the works which relate to the
> (creation of the) world were made by the Son, but also whatsoever
> since that time has been done by God. For the Father who loves the
> Son, and has given all things into His hand, loves Him indeed from the
> beginning, and from the very first has handed all things over to Him.
> Whence it is written, From the beginning the Word was with God, and
> the Word was God; John 1:1 to whom is given by the Father all power in
> heaven and on earth. Matthew 28:18 The Father judges no man, but has
> committed all judgment to the Son John 5:22 — from the very beginning
> even.

Prax. 19

> Inasmuch, then, as the heaven was prepared when Wisdom was present in
> the Word, and since all things were made by the Word, it is quite
> correct to say that even the Son stretched out the heaven alone,
> because He alone ministered to the Father's work. It must also be He
> who says, I am the First, and to all futurity I AM. The Word, no
> doubt, was before all things. In the beginning was the Word; John 1:1
> and in that beginning He was sent forth by the Father. The Father,
> however, has no beginning, as proceeding from none; nor can He be
> seen, since He was not begotten. He who has always been alone could
> never have had order or rank. Therefore, if they have determined that
> the Father and the Son must be regarded as one and the same, for the
> express purpose of vindicating the unity of God, that unity of His is
> preserved intact; for He is one, and yet He has a Son, who is equally
> with Himself comprehended in the same Scriptures.

This alludes back to part of my premise on the slippery terminology that, given a Triune God, differences may be merely contrived. So it seems that as some Church Fathers see it, the scriptural references to inter-Personal differences don't apply or at least don't detract from the unity of the Triune God in terms of each Person having played a role in creation.

I thank all for their input, but I post my own answer because this is more along the lines of what I was trying to unpack (formally and historically).

More information is available at [Against Praxeas](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0317.htm).

Answer (score 1):

We have the following:

- God created all things; Gen 1:1, Ps 33:6, 9, etc
- Jesus is creator of all things; John 1:3, Heb 1:2, Col 1:16, etc
- The Holy Spirit is the creator; Ps 104:30, Gen 1:2, 1 Peter 1:2, Titus 3:3, 4

Now, just how this was accomplished and which of these three did what is not described.  Therefore, this question has no answer. The traditional view is that all three members of the Trinity were involved; just what their function was is not revealed. therefore, we cannot know because we are not told.