# Why was Israel responsible for David's sin?

Tags: history, david, sin, 2-samuel

According to 2 Samuel 24:1:

> ... the anger of Jehovah was kindled against Israel, and he moved David against them ...

Then, David counted the number of Israel. However, it was David's fault. Why did Jehovah make the people responsible for their ruler's error?

Answer (score -1):

- *1st the Holy Identity is not pronounced "yahweh" or "jehovah". There is no verbal pronunciation for the Identity. Nope, Jews did not forget how to pronounce the Name. Any 2ndary partial references are merely 2ndary references the Holy Identity. Any ancient non-Israeli evidence that might exist merely indicates the misconception of ancient neighbours of Israel about the G'd of Israel - simply because they did not know the G'd of Israel. So cannot use pagan sources to tell us how the priesthood "pronounced" the Identity.*

2 Samuel 24 is paralleled/duplicated by 1 Chron 21.

Therefore, I first need to refer you to an answer I wrote for another question: [Are there any published works on the development of "satan/Satan" in the Hebrew Bible to the New Testament?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/25164/are-there-any-published-works-on-the-development-of-satan-satan-in-the-hebrew/25182#25182).

In which I prove that there is no such person with the name "satan".

I also need to again bring out my objection to the inverse-vav theory. Basically, my objection to the inverse-vav theory, is based on the argument that how would such a complicated grammatical set of rules even exist.

- Hebrew has a simplistic sequential-event tenseless grammar. An non-complete/non-finite/future reference, is based on the previous statement. It could be future/propositional subjunctive. Similarly, a completed/past reference is also based on a previous statement - it could also be a past subjunctive stipulating what needs to have happened if the previous statement was made about the future.
- There are sequentially stative languages all over the world. Why did Bible translators try to use european linguistic molds on Hebrew, rather than classify biblical Hebrew as one of those tenseless sequentially stative languages? But they instead then concoct a complicated set of rules and exceptions to fit that grammatical paradigm into biblical Hebrew.
- Read my explanation here: [Shall I Know Pleasure?(Gen. 18:12)](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19192/shall-i-know-pleasuregen-1812/19202#19202)

1 Chron 21:1 should be translated without tenses

> and shall stand a hindrance upon Israel, shall being resistant toward David's census of Israel

i.e., the taxation-census subjunctive-would be a hindrance to Israel, as they subjunctive-would be resistant towards David's taxation-census of Israel.

2 Samuel 24:1 should be translated

> then shall increase anger of Hashem in heat with/in Israel and shall being resistant/apprehended towards David with/in them saying "!go! conduct-census of Israel and Judah"

i.e., the wrath of Hashem as decreed in Torah will be upon Israel for violating this law. So Hashem warns, go on and conduct this taxation-census.

This is a sequence of events.

1. David wants a census. But the primary reason of a Torah-authorized census is for taxation purpose.
2. I'm going to partially lean on [+non-theologian's answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/24986/why-did-god-destroy-70-000-israelites-when-david-conducted-a-census), but not on his/her translation. A law exists of how Israel should respond to a taxation-census.
3. This law guarantees (like the original intention of obamacare) that no one unfairly mooches on the coverage paid by others. You cannot refuse to have insurance coverage, and then when you need it, you mooch on the insurance coverage paid by others.
4. This law is literally a coverage (כפר) that requires full participation.
5. David has gone to too many wars. He wants to conduct more wars. So he issues a taxation-coverage census to further finance his wars.
6. David is warned not to do that. So G'd says, "Go on and do it and see what happens".
7. My translation says, Israel became resistant, because the taxation was a punitive hindrance to the financial well-being of the Israeli public.
8. When a taxation-census is called thro Torah, and people don't respond, they are violating the Torah.

That goes to say, even if you disagree with ObamaCare, you should abide by it and pay your fair share. Well ObamaCare is now its decrepit state as a punishment against you for not supporting the full strength version as had been so well implemented by Mitt Romney in Massachusetts. This question is like asking, why are Americans punished for a sabotaged law? Why do the saboteurs not come out and beg Almighty for forgiveness like David did? It's not fair for me to be punished even though I supported its full strength version (since I had the priv to enjoy Romney's MA version), why should I be punished by consequence of people who sabotaged and watered it down? WHY?

Comment: I have some hesitation as to the point no. 5. According to Exodus 30, the taxation should be offered to "the Lord". It should not be on David's discretion on its usage.

Comment: David had had a history using census-tax for his personal projects - like building a temple when Almighty Allah had insisted He did not need one.

Comment: Would you give support for what you said, because I do not find any record of David using census-tax for projects like building a temple, but Chapter 8 of 2 Samuel recorded that some countries paid tribute to David, and he collected some valuable metals after conquering those countries.